# Google Chart mouse over skipping data point

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Bar Chart that displays fine. The issue is that I have a *tooltip* field in the end used for the hyperlink. The hyperlink itself works fine. 
However, when doing a mouseover each section of the stacked chart, the last one displays the link URL instead of the last data point. It must be a simple thing but this is the first time I'm facing this kind of issue and have tried many things already. 
Here's the code. I appreciate any pointers here.

```
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Draft', 'Submit', 'Backlog', 'Selected', 'In Progress'
         , { role: 'tooltip' } ],
        ['Pri 0 (31)', 0,13,2,8,8,'https://www.google.com'],
        ['Pri 1 (26)', 0,14,4,0,7,'https://www.yahoo.com'],
        ['Pri 2 (48)', 3,33,1,3,11,'https://www.altavista.com'],
        ['Pri 3 (62)', 0,45,5,4,8,'https://www.bing.com'],

      ]);

   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
   view.setColumns([0, 6]);

   var selectHandler = function(e) {
        window.open(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 6 ), '_blank');
        }

  // Add our selection handler.
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart"));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

    var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '75%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
  };

   chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

And here's the resulting chart:

[image]

Comment: when using the tooltip role, you are providing a custom tooltip. you must provide the content to be shown in the tooltip. if you want more than the link itself, then you must add it. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251024/5090771), there are a couple examples. the first, modifies and adds content to the default tooltip on the mouse over event. the second example builds the entire tooltip...

Comment: I see but why doe it show all other tooltips for the bar chart fine but not for the last one (replacing it with the link as in the picture above)? I want it to link properly and that actually works but don't want it to display the link, just the regular tooltip as it does for the other stacked bars

Comment: when using column roles, in this case the tooltip role. the role is applied to the series column it directly follows. so all the other series columns display the default tooltip. the last column has the tooltip role applied, so only displays the content provided...

Comment: Got it, the proposed solution worked, thank you very much. I understand how it works now. If you'd like to add it an answer i'd be glad to mark it as the correct answer.